# Windows 8.1 MediaCapture - how to use snapshot button of webcam

Tags: windows-8.1

We are developing a Windows 8.1 Store-App and using the MediaCapture class to access connected web-cams.
Within the MediaCaptureInitializationSettings we are Setting PhotoCaptureSouce to "Auto".
Works fine including a preview and when the user clicks a button within our App we take the photos.

But now we are using a WebCam with a snapshot button on it.

Any ideas how we can handle this button in our App?